# PHPUnit. Как глобально замокать метод класса?

Tags: php, тестирование, phpunit

Имеется два класса. В классе Two создаем экземпляр класса One в переменную $one.

```
class One 
{
   public function getOne()
   {
       return 1;
   }
}

class Two 
{
   public function getOnePlusTwo()
   {
       $one = new One();
       return $one->getOne() + 2;
   }
}
```

Тест, в котором подменяю возвращаемое значение метода getOne на 2. Ожидаю 4. Но при запуске теста метод getOne все равно возвращает 1, то есть `getMockBuilder` никак не влияет глобально на метод, всего лишь делает копию и орудует ей

```
public function testGetOnePlusTwo()
{
    $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(One::class)
                 ->getMock();
    $mock->method('getOne')
         ->willReturn(2);

    $two = new Two();

    $this->assertEquals(4, $two->getOnePlusTwo());
}
```

При вызове $mock->getOne возвращается 2, все правильно. но при запуске теста getOne возвращает 1.
Не понимаю как замокать метод класса getOne в функции getOnePlusTwo, чтобы возвращать нужные значения. Подскажите?